# mongoose/mongoDB query by one field distinct by another

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have a collection with the following document as an example:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("56fbf2210309775d6790c1c0"),
    city_id: 2600,
    street_name: "hamilton",
    branch: 6
}
```

Is it possible to query the collection by branch but use a distinct on the street_name?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by _"distinct of the street_name"_?

Comment: i can have multiple documents with the same `street_name` if i query by `branch` like this for example: `find({branch: 1})`. I want to be able to get all documents that has `branch: 1` but remove duplications of `street_name` if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean distinct as in unique values only.

You can use

```
db.yourCollectionName.distinct("street_name")
```

It returns an array. In your case, you can use that array as the input and further filter by branch.

mongodb documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

**Edit 1:**

Or, you can pass a second parameter to distinct,

```
//db.collection.distinct(field, query) <-- check out docs.
db.yourCollectionName.distinct( "street_name", { branch: 1 } )
```

Comment: is it possible to do in 1 query?

Comment: Yes, you can add a second parameter to your distinct query as well.

Comment: When i did that, it returns just the `street_name` and not the entire document

Comment: Yes, it returns an array of unique values. If you want the entire documents, you need to provide your logic because they are multiple ways of doing - using [aggregation pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), [mapreduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/), etc.

Comment: My logic will be: Get all documents with `city_id: XXX` and `branch: YYY`. This will return multiple documents with the same `street_name` which i want to remove and be left with only 1 `street_name` per `city_id` and `branch`